# How can I find monthly average of spending in the given dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, data-science

[image]

Given is the snapshot of Spend DataFrame.

Comment: Use `dput(YourDataFrame)` to paste a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of your data](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) into the question itself

Comment: `1.` R is a free, open-source programming language and software environment for statistical computing, bioinformatics, visualization and general computing. **Provide minimal, reproducible, representative example(s) with your questions. Use dput() for data and specify all non-base packages with library calls. Do not embed pictures for data or code, use indented code blocks.** For statistics questions, use stats.stackexchange.com. `2.` calculating the average is not [data-science]. `3.` question has been answered here numerous times.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16652199/compute-monthly-averages-from-daily-data) and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23626299/calculate-average-monthly-total-by-groups-from-data-table-in-r) can help. Possible duplicates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using @Edgar's answer and enhacing it a little:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  group_by(lubridate::month(Month),lubridate::year(Month) ) %>%
  summarise(month_average = mean(Amout))
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that your dataframe is named `df`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  group_by(lubridate::month(Month)) %>%
  summarise(month_average = mean(Amout))
```

Next time, try to [provide a Minimum Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: the problem here is that the `monthly average` would reflect the average of a particulat month of the year, not necessarly the same month.

Comment: If the question is about a particular month in a given year, just add `year(Month)` to the `group_by()` should do it.